databricks autoloader to handle comma in the CSV file
I have the CSV files and in one column called test, its value is "A":123, "B":222
Since the comma shows up in the value, the CSV value shift, test column becomes "A":123 and the next column gets the value "B":222.
How can I handle this in the databricks autoloader?
I cannot change the source CSV file.

Post sample csv file and expected Dataframe you want from it. How many columns does the source csv have? If more than one then it's an invalid csv file. RFC 4180 says "6.  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes.".
